# Netdata Connection Timeout behind Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, netdata

I run netdata on my server to monitor it. Therefore I use an NGINX Reverse Proxy
together with Letsencrypt and the Authorization feature of NGINX to make it accessible via the internet.

```
upstream netdata {
    server localhost:19999;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    server_name netdata.<mydomain>;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/netdata-access.log combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/netdata-error.log error;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://netdata;

        auth_basic "Administrator’s Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    #... Here is the Letsencrypt generated stuf    
}
```

Most of the time when I call the website netdata loads either very slow or not at all.
Sometimes it loads.

When I look in the error logs, I see the following but do not know how to resolve that issue.

```
*66 upstream timed out (110: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream
```

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: Note [netdata documentation recommends manually setting the proxy headers](https://learn.netdata.cloud/guides/step-by-step/step-10#connect-netdata-to-nginx) - keepalive is rather useful for those live-updating charts.

Answer (score 0):

We have created a [tutorial](https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/agent/running-behind-nginx) on how to setup nginx as reverse proxy and authorization gateway for netdata.

If you have any further question, I would be happy to reply!

You can also join our little community at https://community.netdata.cloud